# Using private constructor in a macro

Tags: scala, macros, private-constructor

I want to use a private constructor in a macro. This example is a positive integer, but the basic pattern could not only be used for other numeric types like even numbers, but also string derived types like email addresses or a directory name. By making the constructor private the user is denied the opportunity to make an illegal type. I have the following code:

```
object PosInt
{
  import language.experimental.macros 
  import reflect.runtime.universe._
  import reflect.macros.Context

  def op(inp: Int): Option[PosInt] = if (inp > 0) Some(new PosInt(inp)) else None

  def apply(param: Int): PosInt = macro apply_impl

  def apply_impl(c: Context)(param: c.Expr[Int]): c.Expr[PosInt] =
  {
    import c.universe._
    param match {
      case Expr(Literal(i)) if (i.value.asInstanceOf[Int] > 0) =>
      case Expr(Literal(i)) if (i.value.asInstanceOf[Int] == 0) => c.abort(c.enclosingPosition, "0 is not a positive integer") 
      case Expr(Literal(i)) => c.abort(c.enclosingPosition, "is not a positive integer")      
      case _ => c.abort(c.enclosingPosition, "Not a Literal")
    }    
    reify{new PosInt(param.splice)}    
  }  
}

class PosInt (val value: Int) extends AnyVal
```

However if I make the PosInt Constructor private, although the Macro compiles as expected I get an error if try to use the macro. I can't work out how to build the expression tree manually, but I'm not sure if that would help anyway. Is there anyway I can do this?

You still can't use a private constructor even if PosInt is not a value class. **I'll accept an answer that doesn't use a value class.** The disadvantage of value classes is that they get type erasure. Plus classes that I'm interested in like subsets of 2d co-ordinates can't be implement as value classes anyway. I'm not actually interested in Positive Integers, I'm just using them as a simple test bed. I'm using Scala 2.11M5. Scala 2.11 will have the addition of the quasiquotes feature. I haven't worked out how to use, quasiquotes yet, as all the material at the moment on them seems to assume a familiarity with Macro Paradise, which I don't have.

Comment: I don't think this is possible, but I've just written up a quick [blog post](http://meta.plasm.us/posts/2013/10/03/natural-vampires/) with a sketch of my reasoning and an alternative approach using vampire methods.

Comment: I also don't think this is possible. Looks like the only way to directly satisfy the requirements of the question would be to create a crazily named factory, whose name would repel humans from calling it.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately for what you are trying to achieve, macros do not work this way. They just manipulate the AST at compile time. Whatever the final result is, it is always something you *could* have written literally in Scala (without the macro).

Thus, in order to constrain the possible values of `PosInt`, you will need a runtime check somewhere, either in a public constructor or in a factory method on the companion object.

If runtime exceptions are not palatable to you, then one possible approach would be:

- Make the constructor private on the class.
- Provide (for example) a `create` method on the companion object that returns `Option[PosInt]` (or `Try[PosInt]`, or some other type of your choice that allows you to express a "failure" when the argument is out of range).
- Provide an `apply` method on the companion object similar to your example, which *verifies at compile time that the argument is in range* and then returns an expression tree that simply calls `create(x).get`.

Calling `.get` on the Option is acceptable in this case because you are sure that it will never be `None`.

The downside is that you have to repeat the check twice: once at compile time, and once at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert, but I figured I'll give it a shot...
In Java, the scope of a private constructor is limited to the same class... so the PosInt object would need to be moved into the scope of the same class from which it's being called.
With that said, I found an article that shows two ways you can keep the object from being inherited @ http://www.developer.com/java/other/article.php/3109251/Stopping-Your-Class-from-Being-Inherited-in-Java-the-Official-Way-and-the-Unofficial-Way.htm

It describes using the "final" keyword in the class declaration to prevent it from being inherited. That's the  "official" way. The "unofficial" way is to make the constructor private, but add a public static method that returns an object of the class...

Yes, I know, it is an old question... but it was left unanswered. You never know when an old question will be the top hit in someone's search results...